# What difference is between playing with someone and playing someone?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

> Played myself in scrabble. I won!

What is the difference between ***playing with someone*** and **playing someone**?

What if *someone* is replaced with the speaker themselves?

Is the sentence in the quote correct?

Comment: I mostly know "playing someone" as AAVE slang for BrE ["taking the mickey out of someone"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-take-the-mickey) - making fun of them, usually in an unkind way. Or sometimes *conning* someone. Be careful with *playing with oneself*, because that will often be understood as a sexual reference (inappropriately stimulating one's own genitals! :). But ***to play*** has a vast range of meanings, which can't possibly be covered in a single answer here. Be specific.

Comment: Note: "Is the sentence in the quote correct": Well, the subject "I" has been omitted from the first sentence. This is quite reasonable and common in casual contexts, though it wouldn't be appropriate in formal academic writing. (Also, it only works when the omitted subject is clear as it is here!)

Comment: Alternatively: *Played scrabble with myself. I won!*

Answer (score 3):

For children, playing *with* somebody usually means playing together, and no specific game is implied. For adults "I played with Joe, John and Jack" suggests a more organised activity, perhaps bridge or tennis doubles. "I played with Ronaldo" suggests I was in an Association football team with him. It could mean he and I had a friendly tennis game (against each other), but this would not be the first thing that came to mind. In any case *play with* suggests a friendly relationship with whoever is mentioned.

On the other hand playing somebody means they are your opponent(s). "I played Joe, John and Jack" does not include one of them as a doubles partner, but they could be your opponents in a poker game. When it is "I played", it only makes sense when playing as individuals. For team games it only makes literal sense when a team plays another team, as in "Collingwood played Melbourne", or "Bruce and Betty played Carol and Charles". A figurative use would be to say "Bruce played Melbourne", which would imply that Bruce was the overwhelmingly dominant player in his team.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of games, it's usually "play [person] in/at [game]" or "play [game] with/against [person]". You'd be understood if you mixed them up, but it would sound a little off.

They also have related slang meanings: "Playing with someone" is teasing them or messing with their head (mischievously but not maliciously), while "playing someone" is humiliating them by manipulating them, especially emotionally.

"Playing with oneself" is a euphemism for masturbation, so take great care when using it literally. You can, nevertheless, play a game with yourself, play yourself in a game, or "play yourself" by predictably setting yourself up for failure (tongue-in-cheek, but well-established among young people).